# app crashes while retrieve downloadURL.result

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

As soon as I try to retrieve the downloadUrl of my upload (upload works fine) with `downloadUrl.result` the app crashes. The app does not crash when using `downloadUrl.toString()` instead but that does not give me the downloadUrl as a String. I have read through forums where people had similar problems but I could not resolve mine. Thank you in advance

```
private fun uploadImageToFirebase(){
    val profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg")

    if (uriProfileImage != null) {
        profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                    profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.metadata?.reference?.downloadUrl?.result
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
    }
}
```

debug:

--------- beginning of crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kelbel.frederik.coinz, PID: 17449
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.kelbel.frederik.coinz.FragmentSettings$uploadImageToFirebase$1.onSuccess(FragmentSettings.kt:121)
        at com.example.kelbel.frederik.coinz.FragmentSettings$uploadImageToFirebase$1.onSuccess(FragmentSettings.kt:35)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:123)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zze.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzv.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2:89)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzy.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

logcat:

2018-10-05 16:29:53.732 31185-31758/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.kelbel.frederik.coinz/.ProfileActivity
2018-10-05 16:29:53.855 31185-18160/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-10-05 16:29:53.855 31185-18160/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2018-10-05 16:29:53.855 31185-18160/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2018-10-05 16:29:53.855 31185-18160/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2018-10-05 16:29:53.876 31185-18160/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x96bc2160: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2018-10-05 16:29:53.907 31185-18160/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x96bc2160: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9246d0e0)
2018-10-05 16:29:53.915 31185-18160/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x96bc2160: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9246d0e0)
2018-10-05 16:29:54.246 31185-31207/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{5a43b89 u0 com.example.kelbel.frederik.coinz/.ProfileActivity t153 f}
2018-10-05 16:29:54.271 1311-1339/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4784128
2018-10-05 16:29:54.296 1311-1311/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1311: eglCreateSyncKHR(1962): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2018-10-05 16:29:54.399 31727-31930/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6474700: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x92a170a0)
2018-10-05 16:29:54.517 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/OptInState: There is a new client and it does not support opt-in. Dropping request.
2018-10-05 16:29:54.530 31727-17556/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/LocationOracle: No location history returned by ContextManager
2018-10-05 16:29:54.538 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
2018-10-05 16:29:54.539 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
2018-10-05 16:29:54.553 31727-17936/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
2018-10-05 16:29:54.562 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@88e0935
2018-10-05 16:29:54.571 30990-17939/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa7383e00 ready to run
2018-10-05 16:29:54.577 30990-2569/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-05 16:29:54.578 30990-2569/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xae19cef0, size=4194304)
        0: 0xae19cf00 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        1: 0xae19cf20 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        2: 0xae19cdd0 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        3: 0xae19cb90 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        4: 0xad889180 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        5: 0xae1ff270 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        6: 0xae1ff460 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        7: 0xae1ff500 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        8: 0xae1ff650 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
        9: 0xae1ff980 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       10: 0xae1ff9a0 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       11: 0xae1ff820 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       12: 0xae1ff860 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       13: 0xad889350 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       14: 0xae1ffe40 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       15: 0xae1ffd10 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       16: 0xab0600d0 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       17: 0xab060150 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       18: 0xab060450 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
       19: 0xad8895b0 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 

2018-10-05 16:29:54.579 30990-2569/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-05 16:29:54.579 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-05 16:29:54.584 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-05 16:29:54.584 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-05 16:29:54.584 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@88e0935
2018-10-05 16:29:54.585 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-05 16:29:54.586 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-10-05 16:29:54.591 31706-31796/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb5b05420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb5b033c0)
2018-10-05 16:29:54.620 31727-31746/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4987(326KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 18MB/19MB, paused 6.573ms total 64.756ms
2018-10-05 16:29:54.623 31727-9036/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@88e0935
2018-10-05 16:29:54.625 31727-17936/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
2018-10-05 16:29:54.625 31580-31911/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
2018-10-05 16:29:54.625 31727-17936/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
2018-10-05 16:29:54.626 31727-31988/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
2018-10-05 16:29:54.626 31727-17936/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
2018-10-05 16:29:54.626 31727-17936/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
2018-10-05 16:29:54.631 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
2018-10-05 16:29:54.631 31727-31727/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
2018-10-05 16:29:54.631 31727-17935/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
2018-10-05 16:29:54.646 31580-31911/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
2018-10-05 16:29:54.930 30990-31005/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 79985503 , only wrote 79832880
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now. The task was not finished yet. That is why i could not retrieve the downloadUrl. Added an OnCompleteListener...

```
    taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener{
                            task -> if(task.isSuccessful){
                            profileImageUrl = task.result
                        }else{
                            Log.d("Crash", "Crash starts here")
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  storageReference.putFile(postImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {



                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {

                            String downloadUri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            Map<String, Object> postMap = new HashMap<>();
                            postMap.put("image_download_uri",downloadUri);
                            postMap.put("post_title",title);
                            postMap.put("current_user_id",current_user_id);
                            postMap.put("current_time",currentTime.toString());
                            postMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```