# Unresolved reference downloadurl (Android studio kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

Help me please. Please help me deal with the problem.

Error: Unresolved reference downloadurl

> C:\Users\mayer\Desktop\Instagramapp\app\src\main\java\com\example\instagramapp\activities\EditProfileActivity.kt: (91, 78): Unresolved reference: downloadUrl

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
            mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    mDatabase.child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(it.result!!.downloadUrl.toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: photo saved successfully")
                            } else {
                                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

EditProfileActivity.kt

```
    class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PasswordDialog.Listener {
    private val TAG = "EditProfileActivity"
    private lateinit var mUser: User
    private lateinit var mPendingUser: User
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mStorage: StorageReference
    private val TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US)
    private lateinit var mImageUri: Uri

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

        close_image.setOnClickListener { finish() }
        save_image.setOnClickListener { updateProfile() }
        change_photo_text.setOnClickListener { takeCameraPicture() }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListenerAdapter {
                mUser = it.getValue(User::class.java)!!
                name_input.setText(mUser.name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                username_input.setText(mUser.username, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                website_input.setText(mUser.website, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                bio_input.setText(mUser.bio, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                email_input.setText(mUser.email, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
                phone_input.setText(mUser.phone.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            })
    }

    private fun takeCameraPicture() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            mImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.example.instagramapp.fileprovider",
                imageFile)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri)
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${simpleDateFormat.format(Date())}_",
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
            mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    mDatabase.child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(it.result!!.downloadUrl.toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: photo saved successfully")
                            } else {
                                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun updateProfile() {
        mPendingUser = readInputs()
        val error = validate(mPendingUser)
        if (error == null) {
            if (mPendingUser.email == mUser.email) {
                updateUser(mPendingUser)
            } else {
                PasswordDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, "password_dialog")
            }
        } else {
            showToast(error)
        }
    }

    private fun readInputs(): User {
        val phoneStr = phone_input.text.toString()
        return User(
            name = name_input.text.toString(),
            username = username_input.text.toString(),
            website = website_input.text.toString(),
            bio = bio_input.text.toString(),
            email = email_input.text.toString(),
            phone = if (phoneStr.isEmpty()) 0 else phoneStr.toLong()
        )
    }

    override fun onPasswordConfirm(password: String) {
        if (password.isNotEmpty()) {
            val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(mUser.email, password)
            mAuth.currentUser!!.reauthenticate(credential) {
                mAuth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(mPendingUser.email) {
                    updateUser(mPendingUser)
                }
            }
        } else {
            showToast("You should enter your password")
        }
    }

    private fun updateUser(user: User) {
        val updatesMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        if (user.name != mUser.name) updatesMap["name"] = user.name
        if (user.username != mUser.username) updatesMap["username"] = user.username
        if (user.website != mUser.website) updatesMap["website"] = user.website
        if (user.bio != mUser.bio) updatesMap["bio"] = user.bio
        if (user.email != mUser.email) updatesMap["email"] = user.email
        if (user.phone != mUser.phone) updatesMap["phone"] = user.phone

        mDatabase.updateUser(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid, updatesMap) {
            showToast("Profile saved")
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun validate(user: User): String? =
        when {
            user.name.isEmpty() -> "Please enter name"
            user.username.isEmpty() -> "Please enter username"
            user.email.isEmpty() -> "Please enter email"
            else -> null
        }

    private fun DatabaseReference.updateUser(uid: String, updates: Map<String, Any>,
                                             onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).updateChildren(updates)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess()
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun FirebaseUser.updateEmail(email: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun FirebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential: AuthCredential, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

activity_edit_profile.xml

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.EditProfileActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/close_image"
                    style="@style/toolbar_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/close"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/toolbar_title"
                    android:text="Edit Profile"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/close_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/save_image"
                    style="@style/toolbar_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/check"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/grey"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change_photo_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change photo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/name_input"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/change_photo_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/username_input"
            android:text="Username"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_input" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/website_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/website_input"
            android:text="Website"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/username_input" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/website_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/website_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/bio_input"
            android:text="Bio"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/website_input" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bio_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bio_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/private_info_text"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:text="Private Information"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bio_input" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/email_input"
            android:text="Email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/private_info_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_label"
            style="@style/edit_profile_label"
            android:labelFor="@id/phone_input"
            android:text="Phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_input" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_input"
            style="@style/edit_profile_input"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/phone_label" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.instagramapp">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SearchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ShareActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.LikesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.EditProfileActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"></activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.instagramapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagramapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:29.0.0"

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'

    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: `C:\Users\mayer\Desktop\Instagramapp\app\src\main\java\com\e.........` What is it what you wanna download? That is a path/file on your pc. And your Android app runs on your Android device. How would it have access to files on your pc when you are in town?

Comment: [getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) is asynchronous and returns a Task that will eventually produce the URL.  The documentation shows how to use getDownloadUrl: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the download URL now requires an asynchronous call to the server, so is no longer available as a property on the task. Instead call

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

  if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
    mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
      if (it.isSuccessful) {
        mStorage.child("users/$uid/photo").downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener{
          task -> if(task.isSuccessful){
            mDatabase.child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(task.result)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                  if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: photo saved successfully")
                  } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                  }
            }
          } else {
            showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
          }
        }
    }

}
```

Also see:

- The Firebase documentation on [downloading a file via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669752

Answer (score 0):

result.downloadUrl is deprecated now use it by this way

```
if (it.isSuccessful) {

                    mDatabase.child("users/$uid/photo").setValue(it.result!!.toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: photo saved successfully")
                            } else {
                                showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
```

for more check this "[taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467814/tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl-is-deprecated)"

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to call `getDownloadUrl`. Can you show how to do so in Kotlin, instead of only linking to an answer that shows how to do it in Java?